# How to enable thumbnails for flac files in Nautilus?

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, thumbnails, flac

Somehow I managed it to get thumbnails for flac audio files, which have covers included in their tags, to show up in Ubuntu version 11.10. But since I reinstalled for Ubuntu 12.04, they don't show up anymore and I don't know which package I need to install to re-enable.

I've already installed "ffmpegthumbnailer", "ffmpegthumbs", "kdegraphics-thumbnailers", "kffmpegthumbnailer", "mplayerthumbs" packages. Do I need "tumbler" to get it working again ?

One possible reason:
It may be possible that some PPAs I used in 11.10 contained newer version of the thumbnailers than shipped with Ubuntu 12.04. If somebody could point me to the right package I could update it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this problem by adding repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3 and upgrading the system.
Totem was updated: I think that was "it".
Hope it'll help.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, but **yes!** it works now. Seems I had missed that ppa after the installation of Ubuntu 12.04. Thank you!