# Show image tags of flac on Nautilus

Tags: gnome, nautilus, flac, nautilus-extensions

When I was on Arch Linux, using gnome-shell, nautilus was able to show all images tagged on my music files using [Easytag](http://easytag.sourceforge.net/) as thumbnails. I am using Ubuntu now, with gnome-shell, but for some reason, nautilus can't show the album images of my flac files, showing a generic music icon for each one. It shows the images of MP3 files. How can I configure nautilus to search for flac tags and make it show them instead of the music icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem doing [this suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131599/how-to-enable-thumbnails-for-flac-files-in-nautilus). After installing the [gnome 3 repository](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3) and updating the system, nautilus can now show flac thumbnails in Ubuntu 12.04.